# Hide tab panels except default

Tags: jquery, tabs, hide

I have tabs that display all panels while loading. Although it reverts to showing only default one but it is creating problems in an iframe height setting. After some searching I found this jquery. First hiding the other panels with css

```
.hide { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; }
```

And jquery to replace hide class is

```
    // Accessible hiding fix
        $(".hide").css({
            "position": "relative",
            "top": 0,
            "left": 0,
            "display": "none"
        });
```

At first it appears good, but after switching tabs it displays panel contents together. So whichever tab is clicked the third time, it mixes all content with the previous tab

I am not sure what to do here. Here is link to the full page.
http://tinyurl.com/c5nhet5

How should I fix the code to get rid of this?

Comment: Why not just remove the class? `$(".hide").removeClass("hide")`

Comment: @kevin-b
Tried that. But then it displays all tab contents at once. It does seem to work when switching tabs but the initial impression is now screwed. any way around?

Comment: are you removing the class before or after you initialize the tabs. It should be done after.

Comment: It breathes now. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just remove the hide class rather than trying to override what it does.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".hide").removeClass("hide");
```